# Problema para mostrar o valor no dicionário que corresponde a resposta do usuário

Tags: python-3.x, dicionário

```
bebidas = {'Suco de laranja': 5.99, 'Suco de uva': 5.99, 'Suco de açaí': 5.99, 'Coca Cola(lata)': 6.50, 'Vitamina': 7.50 }
simounão = int(input('Olá, gostaria de ver nosso menu\n\n[1]Sim\n[2]Não\n\n'))
while simounão != 1:
    simounão = int(input('Olá, gostaria de ver nosso menu\n\n[1]Sim\n[2]Não\n\n'))
escolha1 = str(input('Qual suco você deseja?\n\n[ ]Suco de laranja\n[ ]Suco de uva\n[ ]Suco de açaí\n[ ]Coca Cola(lata)\n[ ]Vitamina\n'))
for escolha1 in bebidas:
#Não sei o que colocar dentro do print abaixo, se a resposta da "escolha1" for, por exemplo, Suco de laranja    
    print()
```

Comment: Formata direito essa pergunta, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acessar a chave de um dicionário use a seguinte síntaxe:

> nomedodicionario[nomedachave]

Melhorei seu código, aqui está:

```
bebidas = {'Suco de laranja': 5.99, 'Suco de uva': 5.99, 'Suco de açaí': 5.99, 'Coca Cola(lata)': 6.50, 'Vitamina': 7.50 }
    while (True):
        sn = int(input('Olá, gostaria de ver nosso menu:\n\n[1]Sim\n[2]Não\n\n'))
        if sn!=1: break
        escolha1 = str(input('Qual suco você deseja?\n\n[1]Suco:'))    
        if escolha1 in bebidas:print(bebidas[escolha1])#acessando o dicionário.
        else: print("Opção não encontrada")
```

Dica muito importante para ser corrigida logo agora que você está aprendendo a programar.

> 1 - NUNCA USE acentos para nomear variáveis.

Comment: Como não estudei estruturas de repetição e loop completamente, eu mudei apenas o que eu consegui entender do seu código, e deu certo, mas a resposta ficou repetindo 5 vezes.https://repl.it/MQ1g/0

Comment: Pra que você tá passando um for em dicionário? Isso vai contra o principio do dicionário.